# Rendezvous between two accelerating objects from opposite sides

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics

I have two objects. Object 1 is travelling from A to B, a distance of (let's say) 1,000,000km. It can accelerate at 2g, and will accelerate up to the halfway point and then decelerate until the end (so initial and final velocity are both 0m/s).

Object 2 is already at B, can accelerate at 20g, and wants to intercept object 1 as soon as possible after object 1 leaves A. It has to not just reach the same position as object 1, but be at the same speed as object 1 when it intercepts.

In essence, object 2 must accelerate toward object 1, then turn around and accelerate the opposite direction, so that it matches speed with object 1 when the two meet, in the shortest possible time.

Is there a (set of) formula(s) I can use to solve this problem?

This is not homework; I need this for a science fiction story I'm writing.

Comment: Have you tried your hand at solving this?

Comment: Hi and welcome to Physics SE! You have probably noticed that a [tag:homework-and-exercises] tag has been added to your question. In case this is confusing (since you specified your question to be no homework), it is because it could still be considered homework-_like_. I hope this prevents possible confusion.

Comment: I don't even really know where to start. Calculating with constant acceleration is easy, but I don't know how to handle the deceleration phase. Because of that, I can't think of a way to describe object 1's position over time in a single formula. If I had that, it would be a start.

As a software engineer, the only way I could think to solve this myself would be to brute force it in a simulation, but I was hoping for a more elegant solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here are the equations

$V_A = 2gT$,  where $T$ is the total time of travel.

$V_B = -20gT_1+20gT_2$  , where $T_1$ is for the first part of Bs journey and $T_2$ for the second part.

$T=T_1+T_2$

$V_A = V_B$

$S_A = S_B$ , where these distances are measured from A positive towards B

$S_A=0.5(2g)T^2$

$S_B=1\times10^9+0.5(-20g){T_1}^2-20gT_1T_2+0.5(20g){T_2}^2$

7 equations with 7 unknowns, solving with g=9.8 gives $T_1 = 2043.134$, $T_2=2497.1639$ and the distance $S=2.020202\times10^8$m from A.

Comment: B's distance is the trickiest, the 3rd and 4th terms are from the equation of motion often written as $s=ut+0.5at^2$, and u is the velocity at the start of the second part of the motion, $-20gT_1$

Comment: The question also lists the condition that at the moment of Object 2 overtaking Object 1 the two speeds must match. In my answer I stated that I think that speeds-must-match condition cannot be met. The speeds-must-match condition is not among your equations. Suggestion: state explicitly that you dropped the speeds-must-match condition.

Comment: It's the 4th equation down

Comment: This does seem to ignore the deceleration of object 1, but I guess since the intercept happens before the halfway point it doesn't matter.

Comment: *In essence, object 2 must accelerate toward object 1, then turn around and accelerate the opposite direction, so that it matches speed with object 1 when the two meet* Is that criterium met by your solution? It's not clear to me.

Comment: Shoot; I was wrong on both accounts. In the question the problem is stated as an optimization problem. As you demonstrate, the speeds-must-match condition *can* be met, and in fact it turns the problem into one with an *exact* solution, instead of being an optimization problem.

Comment: Here's a [Sage script](https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJwljsEOgjAMhu97iiYcWGHitkQiJnsLbwSMUSSLOswoPL8d9NCmX778LSkyiiw4WO9R5rSvOYqRUVOdIUtd1_VJzNMnMOSxDrIlcA7IQAlkFWyb0YXkqANjVAKot4lKo_sGjyPzTTCMS7AFmWKXbW-xSz7HGLXF8Y2F_BRuT_8gd43LgCL7RR9Ipi9QvKYIbwUr-JDk0Oqu8jR8Z4kXAVy7nJQqSMQ_nJ49vg==&lang=sage) that solves these equations (in slightly simplified form), which produces the same numeric values.

Comment: @Gert Yes, object 2 reverses its acceleration at $T_1$. That's handled properly in the equations for $V_B$ & $S_B$.

Comment: @Sven - hope it answers your question.  Does anyone think a quicker time might be possible if B chooses to not always use it's maximum acceleration?  That wasn't clear, but it's likely that there wouldn't be an improvement...would be interesting to know for sure

Answer (score 0):

This kind of problem does not quite lend itself to be solved with some set of mathematical expressions because of the following: over time the acceleration of each of the objects has a discontinuity: Object 1 is described as having the direction of acceleration reverse at the halfway point.

With object 1 at least you know in advance when the change of reversal of direction of acceleration occurs. But of course the moment in time of the reversal of acceleration of Object 2 is the very thing you are looking for.

It appears to me that drawing graphs will be a good strategy here.

I just did an internet search with the search terms:

online function plotting

There are multiple websites offering an environment for plotting functions.

The plot of the position of Object 1 as a function of time is a given: with uniform acceleration the position as a function of time is a parabola. To plot the trajectory of Object 1 you need to declare a pair of functions: one for the stretch from start to halfway, the other for the stretch from halfway to the end point.

Then you declare a pair of functions for the position-as-a-function-of-time for Object 2.
For that pair you implement a shared variable for the point in time when Object 1 reverses its direction of acceleration.

From there it will be trial-and-error. You shift the point of acceleration reversal of Object 2 to find the earliest point that allows Object 2 to overtake object 1 before Object 1 completes its journey.

In addition, by tweaking the ratio of acceleration of Object 1 and Object 2 you can look for a scenario that maximizes dramatic effect.

The advantage of a graphing approach, I think, is that once you have homed in on the answer you will know with certainty that it is the optimum you are looking for. I assume it can also be solved with formula's, but then (I think) there will be gnawing doubt that maybe there could be an error somewhere.